# How does spring security's <intercept-url> work.. ?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I have several `<intercept-url>` in my `spring-security` XML. I just have this small doubt. Suppose I have something like :

```
<intercept-url pattern="/data/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN" />
```

Since the below `<intercept-url>` has a pattern of `/**` I was wondering if the second URL over-rides the first one. E.g. I gt acess to /data/** even if I am a USER.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote from the [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html):

> You can use multiple `<intercept-url>` elements to define different access requirements for different sets of URLs, but they will be evaluated in the order listed and the first match will be used. So you must put the most specific matches at the top.

As long as the rule for `/**` is listed later, it won't override the more specific rule for `/data/**`.

As jpprade suggested already, if you get access to `/data/**` as a plain user with the above rules, there must be some other problem with your configuration. In that case share your web.xml and the whole security config to troubleshoot that.

Answer (score 1):

The second doesn't overides the first one, in theory it is the first matched rules which is applied.

if you can access /data/** as USER maybe it is because your miss something in the configuration, maybe the filter declaration ?

Comment: Thanks @jpprade for the repsonse. :) .. Will check the configuration. :)